# Replace find Special characters string - Batch

Tags: string, batch-file

Thank you, with your hint I have adjusted my main batch file but variable TARG_FILE is not changing.
I am trying to extract the file name from FileList_for_Import.txt which contains data as

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

`

```
Cls
DIR /o-d /b D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\*.* > D:\Data\FileList_for_Import.txt

REM Start Loop thru the file names that are available in FileList_for_Import.txt
REM Loop thru file

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
Set AllInputFile= D:\Data\FileList_for_Import.txt
SET INTEXTFILE=C:\DataLoader\Load.xml
set OUTTEXTFILE=D:\Data\tmp_out.txt
SET BackupPath=D:\Data\BackupLoad.xml
Set TempFile=D:\Data\tmp.txt
SET DbgFile=D:\Data\debuginfo.txt
Rem Remove Debug files
  Del !DbgFile!
 REM  Del D:\Data\debugerr.txt
ECHO " Start ">!DbgFile!
ECHO  !AllInputFile!>>!DbgFile!

ECHO  " "###########Start of MAIN OF LOOP ############"
REM pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (!AllInputFile!) do (     
  set "TARG_FILE=%%a"
  REM ECHO line=%%a "TARG_FILE "!TARG_FILE!>>!DbgFile!

  REM Get the 2nd line from the debugpayload file
  REM for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" C:\DataLoader\Load.xml') do if %%G equ 2  set "DbgLine=%%H"  
   REM ECHO  " "DbgLine "!DbgLine!>>!DbgFile! 
     Del !TempFile!
    REM Copy !INTEXTFILE! !BackupPath!
   findstr /g "InFilePath" !INTEXTFILE!>!TempFile!
   REM set /p "DbgLine="< !TempFile!
   set /p DbgLine=< !TempFile!
   ECHO  "DbgLine "!DbgLine!>>!DbgFile! 
   SET PREVFILE_NM=!DbgLine:~75,-13!
   ECHO  "PREVFILE_NM "!PREVFILE_NM! "TARG_FILE " !TARG_FILE! "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!

  set FinalreplaceLine=!DbgLine!
  REM ECHO  "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!
   set FinalreplaceLine=!FinalreplaceLine:%PREVFILE_NM%=%TARG_FILE%! 
  ECHO  "FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!

   )
```

`
Output of this batch is as 
!TARG_FILE! is getting with each iteration as

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

but with the below statement it replaces as file1.txt in the first iteration and in second iteration it value doesn't change doesnt replace.

```
set FinalreplaceLine=!FinalreplaceLine:%PREVFILE_NM%=%TARG_FILE%!
```

Thanks in advance for your help or valuable suggestions.

Comment: Check my EDIT for the loop problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is working on my computer ???
but you can try like this :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET DbgFile=D:\Data\debuginfo.txt

::*******REM This block doesnt work********
set string="        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
  set FinalreplaceLine=!string!
  set PREVFILE_NM=oldfile.txt
  set TARG_FILE=newfile.txt
  ECHO  "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>!DbgFile!
   set FinalreplaceLine=!FinalreplaceLine:%PREVFILE_NM%=%TARG_FILE%! 
  ECHO  "FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!
```

EDIT :

I make a file filelist.txt with

```
toto.txt
titi.txt
tata.txt
```

this will be the replacing name of fileold.txt.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET DbgFile=D:\Data\debuginfo.txt

for /f "delims=" %%a in (FileList.txt) do call:replace "%%a"
exit/b

:replace

set string="        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
  set FinalreplaceLine=!string!
  set PREVFILE_NM=oldfile.txt
  set TARG_FILE=%~1
  ECHO  "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!
   set FinalreplaceLine=!FinalreplaceLine:%PREVFILE_NM%=%TARG_FILE%! 
  ECHO  "FinalreplaceLine "!FinalreplaceLine!>>!DbgFile!
```

Output in DebugInfo.txt :

```
 "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
 "FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\toto.txt</InFilePath>"  
 "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
 "FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\titi.txt</InFilePath>"  
 "Before Replace FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\oldfile.txt</InFilePath>" 
 "FinalreplaceLine ""        <InFilePath>D:\Data\All_Inputfiles\tata.txt</InFilePath>"
```